# How to add a view inside a view?

Tags: entities, views

I have 2 groups of blocks in a view, I would like to join both of them in one view, showing the first block (I have the groups all linked one to the other).
I did download Views Field View but I can not manage the way to get it work, joining these 2 views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module '[Views Field View](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view)' that you have mentioned is very good imo. In order to use it, you have to edit a view A and add another existing view B as a *field* of view A.

But this is as far as it gets, it does not facilitate a 'joining' of views of any sort, for that matter I think it would be better for you to rebuild a new view with relationships etc, if Views Field View is not adequate for you.

Comment: Thanks you very much , it sounds very good, but now that I am thinking deeply into that I think my problem is that I have 2 images in my view and those images have to be linked to one different link each one and I can not get it, I am using quicktabs to build a page, so I want to link one image to one different quicktab view. its more that the problem, so what I thought was to join to views sothat I could add each view as field, but I can not get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the second "block" as "attachment" display (instead of the block display) and choose "block 1" on your new attachment display.

Attachments are very handy in this kind of situations.

About view displays:
[What is the purpose of Views "Attachment", "Content pane" & "Context"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47774/what-is-the-purpose-of-views-attachment-content-pane-context)