# Is it possible for a view to have two outputs

Tags: 7, views

The reason I need this because I create a view to search through document and need two outputs. One being the document and the other being the files are part of the document group the file is associated with.

*Is this possible with one exposed filter

Thanks for any help with this

Comment: You mean 2 sections on one page? Or 2 separate pages generated from one view?

Comment: two section on one page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an attached View. An attached View is a View display that is attached to another View display, a compounded View.

In this question is explained its purpose:
[What is the purpose of Views "Attachment", "Content pane" & "Context"?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47774/what-is-the-purpose-of-views-attachment-content-pane-context)

> The Attachment option is to create yet another view that you can attach before and/or after any of the displays on your current view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views Field View](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view); allows you to embed a view as a field in a view.

It can accept arguments from fields of the parent view using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use attached view. Attached view have view display before or after to page or master. So u can easily attached another views on same page