# node access by related fields

Tags: 7, views

I have created the following List field type of checkboxes to allow users to select their own content's privacy settings when creating a node called RideShares:

```
1|me only
2|any registered site member
3|users on the same flights as me
4|users arriving at the same airport during the same week as me.
5|public
```

I can use the exposed filter to manually select any matching nodes, but do not know how to automatically filter the queried RideShares to the current user's data in other bundle/content types. For example, whether the current user has entered a Flight into where the destination airpor catches one of the existing RideShares.

It seems this cannot be done with context filters in Views.

Comment: I am having trouble deciphering your penultimate sentence: "For example, whether the current user has entered a Flight into where the destination airpor catches one of the existing RideShares."  Can you provide more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can use the exposed filter to manually select any matching nodes,
>   but do not know how to automatically filter the queried RideShares to
>   the current user's data in other bundle/content types. For example,
>   whether the current user has entered a Flight into where the
>   destination airpor catches one of the existing RideShares.

Views is a simple query builder. Typically this would be SQL like `Select * From RideShares Where city = 'denver'`. Your question cannot be expressed in single SQL expression you would need `JOINs` in SQL of PHP and multiple queries to arrive at an answer.

Your talking about *relating* a set of results with additional logic or data-sources.

This can be done in Drupal using a combination of [Views Relationships](https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004) perhaps [Attachment Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47774/what-is-the-purpose-of-views-attachment-content-pane-context) to build results you want.

For example I might create a [Nodequeue](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) of `uids` that are `users on the same flights as me` and examine a View result that uses the Nodequeue as a `Filter` against the current user to see if that logic produces any results.

You could then place many view `blocks` on a single page that acts as a search results page. Each block can be a View with many view-attachments, etc.

Comment: thanks @tenken! i'll try this tonight, but it would seem faster to select the initally filtered list, the loop over and unset nodes that doen't match the current user's data. is there a hook after the view has run it's queries in order to edit the data?